# Compiling a Qt Project with CEF

Tags: visual-studio, qt, dll, linker, chromium-embedded

I have some troubles trying to compile a Qt project with chromium embedded framework. It complains about not being able to read a .lib file that I created and compiled with VS2010, `:-1: error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'libcef_dll_wrapperd.lib'`.

The below is the configuration of my .pro file. The commented out lines are some of the things that I tried.

```
QT       += core gui webkit webkitwidgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

#LIBS += -L"C:\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows32\Release" -llibcef
#LIBS += "C:\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows32\out\Release\lib\libcef_dll_wrapper.lib" # "C:\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows32\Release\libcef.dll"
INCLUDEPATH += C:\cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows32
DEFINES += NOMINMAX

TARGET = browser
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    clientapp.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    clientapp.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../../cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows32/out/Release/lib/ -llibcef_dll_wrapper
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../../cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows32/out/Release/lib/ -llibcef_dll_wrapperd

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../../../cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows32/out/Release
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../../../cef_binary_3.1547.1412_windows32/out/Release
```

I compiled the chromium embedded framework with the default settings, and I do not understand why I am receiving a "cannot open file" error when I am trying to link to it.

Comment: I know this is old, but I just had the same issue. Looks like `libcef_dll_wrapper.lib` lives in Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 designated folders. I didn't bother to try to figure out how to get this to work in VS 2010, but opening the project in 2013 solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed the existence of `libcef_dll_wrapperd.lib`?

*Maybe you should change `libcef_dll_wrapperd.lib` to `libcef_dll_wrapper.lib`.*

Or you can try this project [qtcefclient](https://github.com/joinAero/qtcefclient) (a simple cef3 client with Qt).